# A way to mock satalites data (count, SNRs)

Tags: android, mocking, gps, location

LocationManager.addTestProvider() gives an easy way to mock the location. However, in this case, LocationManager.getGPSStatus() still returns empty data and this can cause software to think that there is no GPS signal. Is there a way to control the data which is returned by getGPSStatus()?

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter around LocationManager. Have this API adapt, aka work the way you want. Easier to mock plus you can control what you return each time.

Comment: My problem is that there are two different applications. application #1 is using the location and application #2 mocking it. I don't have control over application #1. The location mocking works fine but the application also checks getGPSStatus and fails.